# Can we send notification request to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app in react native using firebase and I can't find if it is possible to send notification TO firebase.
More precisely, I want to send some kind of notification request to firebase so Firebase send notifications to devices.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).

What you'll need:

- A server to use FCM admin SDK (you can use Firebase Cloud Functions as well)
- The device's FCM token that you want to send the notification to

Also take a look to [In-App messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging).